# Как остановить дополнительный поток нажатием кнопки?

Tags: python, многопоточность, pyqt5, qthread, pyside6

Необходимо помощь в решении следующей проблемы:

На главном окне есть кнопка (`pushButton_2`), которая должна останавливать дополнительный поток. Но она не работает.

Не могу понять, что я делаю не так. Прошу подсказать как решить данную проблему.

**main.py**:

```
import sys
from PySide6.QtWidgets import *
from Controller.Potok_Controller import Potok_Controller
from View.ui_potok import Ui_MainWindow


class MainWindow(QMainWindow):
    def __init__(self, parent=None):
        super(MainWindow, self).__init__(parent)

        self.ui = Ui_MainWindow()
        self.ui.setupUi(self)
        self.myThread = Potok_Controller()
        self.ui.pushButton.clicked.connect(self.open_window)
        self.ui.pushButton_2.clicked.connect(self.stop)

    def open_window(self):
        self.myThread.mysignal.connect(lambda text: self.ui.plainTextEdit.appendPlainText(text))
        self.myThread.start()
    def stop(self):
        self.myThread.stop = False
if __name__ == '__main__':
    app = QApplication()
    window = MainWindow()
    window.show()
    sys.exit(app.exec())
```

**ui_potok.py**:

```
from PySide6.QtCore import (QCoreApplication, QDate, QDateTime, QLocale,
    QMetaObject, QObject, QPoint, QRect,
    QSize, QTime, QUrl, Qt)
from PySide6.QtGui import (QBrush, QColor, QConicalGradient, QCursor,
    QFont, QFontDatabase, QGradient, QIcon,
    QImage, QKeySequence, QLinearGradient, QPainter,
    QPalette, QPixmap, QRadialGradient, QTransform)
from PySide6.QtWidgets import (QApplication, QFrame, QMainWindow, QPlainTextEdit,
    QPushButton, QSizePolicy, QVBoxLayout, QWidget)

class Ui_MainWindow(object):
    def setupUi(self, MainWindow):
        if not MainWindow.objectName():
            MainWindow.setObjectName(u"MainWindow")
        MainWindow.resize(800, 600)
        self.centralwidget = QWidget(MainWindow)
        self.centralwidget.setObjectName(u"centralwidget")
        self.verticalLayout = QVBoxLayout(self.centralwidget)
        self.verticalLayout.setObjectName(u"verticalLayout")
        self.frame = QFrame(self.centralwidget)
        self.frame.setObjectName(u"frame")
        self.frame.setFrameShape(QFrame.StyledPanel)
        self.frame.setFrameShadow(QFrame.Raised)
        self.verticalLayout_2 = QVBoxLayout(self.frame)
        self.verticalLayout_2.setObjectName(u"verticalLayout_2")
        self.plainTextEdit = QPlainTextEdit(self.frame)
        self.plainTextEdit.setObjectName(u"plainTextEdit")

        self.verticalLayout_2.addWidget(self.plainTextEdit)


        self.verticalLayout.addWidget(self.frame)

        self.frame_2 = QFrame(self.centralwidget)
        self.frame_2.setObjectName(u"frame_2")
        self.frame_2.setFrameShape(QFrame.StyledPanel)
        self.frame_2.setFrameShadow(QFrame.Raised)
        self.verticalLayout_3 = QVBoxLayout(self.frame_2)
        self.verticalLayout_3.setObjectName(u"verticalLayout_3")
        self.pushButton = QPushButton(self.frame_2)
        self.pushButton.setObjectName(u"pushButton")

        self.verticalLayout_3.addWidget(self.pushButton)

        self.pushButton_2 = QPushButton(self.frame_2)
        self.pushButton_2.setObjectName(u"pushButton_2")

        self.verticalLayout_3.addWidget(self.pushButton_2)


        self.verticalLayout.addWidget(self.frame_2)

        MainWindow.setCentralWidget(self.centralwidget)

        self.retranslateUi(MainWindow)

        QMetaObject.connectSlotsByName(MainWindow)
    # setupUi

    def retranslateUi(self, MainWindow):
        MainWindow.setWindowTitle(QCoreApplication.translate("MainWindow", u"MainWindow", None))
        self.pushButton.setText(QCoreApplication.translate("MainWindow", u"Start Thread", None))
        self.pushButton_2.setText(QCoreApplication.translate("MainWindow", u"Stop Thread", None))
    # retranslateUi
```

Код класса где реализован `Thread`:

```
import time

from PySide6.QtCore import QThread, Signal
from selenium import webdriver

class Potok_Controller(QThread):
    mysignal = Signal(str)
    finish_signal = Signal()
    def __init__(self, parent=None):
        super(Potok_Controller, self).__init__(parent)
        self.url = ['https://google.com/', 'https://youtube.com/']
        self.stop = True

    def txt(self):
        while self.stop == True:
            for url in self.url:
                self.mysignal.emit(f'open {url}')
                chrome = webdriver.Chrome(executable_path='chromedriver\\chromedriver.exe')
                chrome.get(url=f"{url}")
                time.sleep(10)
                chrome.close()
                chrome.quit()
                #chrome.save_screenshot('datadome_regular_webdriver.png')
        self.finish_signal.emit()

    def run(self):
        self.txt()
```

Comment: Владислав, как у вас написано, так все и работает. Напишите лучше, что вы хотите сделать. Какие действия вы выполняете и что при этом получаете и что не так в том что вы получаете, т.е. что вы ожидали получить.

Comment: @S. Nick - при нажатии на кнопку stop хочу получить результат остановки потока, то есть если открылся первый сайт я нажимаю кнопку и поток останавливает свою работу. Если бы в листе было бы 4 сайта то например программа открывает 2 или 3 или 1 сайт и я нажимаю на кнопку и поток останавливает работу, но на данный момент этого не происходит и я не могу понять почему.

Answer (score 2):

Если я вас правильно понял, вам надо добавить проверку, например:

```
            if not self.stop:
                continue
```

Да, я немного упорядочил ваш модуль **main.py**. 
Поменяйте импорты и раскомментируйте строки, связанные с `webdriver`.

---

**main.py**

```
import sys
'''
from PySide6.QtWidgets import *
'''
from PyQt5 import QtCore, QtGui, QtWidgets
from PyQt5.Qt import *

#from Controller.Potok_Controller import Potok_Controller
from q1436700_Potok_Controller import Potok_Controller

#from View.ui_potok import Ui_MainWindow
class Ui_MainWindow(object):
    def setupUi(self, MainWindow):
        if not MainWindow.objectName():
            MainWindow.setObjectName(u"MainWindow")
        MainWindow.resize(400, 300)
        self.centralwidget = QWidget(MainWindow)
        self.centralwidget.setObjectName(u"centralwidget")
        self.verticalLayout = QVBoxLayout(self.centralwidget)
        self.verticalLayout.setObjectName(u"verticalLayout")
        self.frame = QFrame(self.centralwidget)
        self.frame.setObjectName(u"frame")
        self.frame.setFrameShape(QFrame.StyledPanel)
        self.frame.setFrameShadow(QFrame.Raised)
        
        self.verticalLayout_2 = QVBoxLayout(self.frame)
        self.verticalLayout_2.setObjectName(u"verticalLayout_2")
        self.plainTextEdit = QPlainTextEdit(self.frame)
        self.plainTextEdit.setObjectName(u"plainTextEdit")
        self.verticalLayout_2.addWidget(self.plainTextEdit)
        self.verticalLayout.addWidget(self.frame)

        self.frame_2 = QFrame(self.centralwidget)
        self.frame_2.setObjectName(u"frame_2")
        self.frame_2.setFrameShape(QFrame.StyledPanel)
        self.frame_2.setFrameShadow(QFrame.Raised)
        self.verticalLayout_3 = QVBoxLayout(self.frame_2)
        self.verticalLayout_3.setObjectName(u"verticalLayout_3")
        self.pushButton = QPushButton(self.frame_2)
        self.pushButton.setObjectName(u"pushButton")
        self.verticalLayout_3.addWidget(self.pushButton)
        self.pushButton_2 = QPushButton(self.frame_2)
        self.pushButton_2.setObjectName(u"pushButton_2")
        self.verticalLayout_3.addWidget(self.pushButton_2)
        self.verticalLayout.addWidget(self.frame_2)

        MainWindow.setCentralWidget(self.centralwidget)
        self.retranslateUi(MainWindow)
        QMetaObject.connectSlotsByName(MainWindow)

    def retranslateUi(self, MainWindow):
        MainWindow.setWindowTitle(QCoreApplication.translate("MainWindow", u"MainWindow", None))
        self.pushButton.setText(QCoreApplication.translate("MainWindow", u"Start Thread", None))
        self.pushButton_2.setText(QCoreApplication.translate("MainWindow", u"Stop Thread", None))


class MainWindow(QMainWindow, Ui_MainWindow):
    def __init__(self, parent=None):
        super(MainWindow, self).__init__(parent)
        self.setupUi(self)
        
        self.pushButton.clicked.connect(self.open_window)
        self.pushButton_2.clicked.connect(self.stop)
        self.pushButton_2.setEnabled(False)
        
        self.myThread = Potok_Controller()
        self.myThread.mysignal.connect(
            lambda text: self.plainTextEdit.appendPlainText(text))
        self.myThread.finish_signal.connect(lambda: print('finish_signal'))

    def open_window(self):
        self.myThread.stop = True
        self.pushButton.setEnabled(False)
        self.pushButton_2.setEnabled(True)
        self.myThread.start()
        
    def stop(self):
        self.myThread.stop = False
        self.pushButton.setEnabled(True)
        self.pushButton_2.setEnabled(False)
        
        
if __name__ == '__main__':
    app = QApplication(sys.argv)
    window = MainWindow()
    window.show()
    sys.exit(app.exec())
```

**q1436700_Potok_Controller.py**

```
# ???import time

#from selenium import webdriver
'''
from PySide6.QtCore import QThread, Signal                          # PySide6
'''
from PyQt5 import QtCore, QtGui, QtWidgets                          # PyQt5
from PyQt5.Qt import *                                              # PyQt5


class Potok_Controller(QThread):
    '''
    mysignal = Signal(str)                                          # PySide6
    finish_signal = Signal()                                        # PySide6
    '''
    mysignal = pyqtSignal(str)                                      # PyQt5
    finish_signal = pyqtSignal()                                    # PyQt5
    
    def __init__(self, parent=None):
        super(Potok_Controller, self).__init__(parent)
        self.url = ['https://google.com/', 'https://youtube.com/', ]
        self.stop = True

    def txt(self):
        while self.stop == True:

            for url in self.url:
            
# +++ vvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvv            
                if not self.stop:
                    continue
# +++ ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^

                self.mysignal.emit(f'open {url}')
#                chrome = webdriver.Chrome(executable_path='chromedriver\\chromedriver.exe')
#                chrome.get(url=f"{url}")

# ???                time.sleep(10)
                self.msleep(10 * 1000)
                
#                chrome.close()
#                chrome.quit()
                #chrome.save_screenshot('datadome_regular_webdriver.png')
                
        self.finish_signal.emit()

    def run(self):
        self.txt()
```

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: Скорее всего, ему надо не continue, a break

Comment: @AlexanderChernin я же написал  `например`.

Comment: @Владислав что не так?